# Jmeter not finishing because of daemon threads

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jmeter, jsch

I am trying to run a `JMX` file from non GUI mode on `linux` server. Using `SFTP` protocol trying to upload file to object store. Below is the script and configuration used to run the script.

**Test.jmx**

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

def jsch = new JSch()
def session = jsch.getSession("user1", "xyz", 4000) 
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setPassword("password")
def sftpSession = session.connect()
def channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
channel.connect();
def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
log.info("SFTP Connection with host is acquired" + channelSftp)
channelSftp.cd("/0002/test/upload/r9a1");
def f1 = new File("/home/dc-user/Files/test_exact5mb.txt");
channelSftp.put(new java.io.FileInputStream(f1), f1.getName()+ Math.random());
session.disconnect()
```

Configuration used is 
No of Threads - 150
Ramp up period - 1
Loop Count -1

After running the script, out of 150 files sometimes 126 or 129 or 141 files gets uploaded but not 150.
Below is the error i see on terminal

```
The JVM should have exited but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[Connect thread 10.157.147.242 session,5,main], stackTrace:java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead0
java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead at line:116
java.net.SocketInputStream#read at line:171
java.net.SocketInputStream#read at line:141
com.jcraft.jsch.IO#getByte at line:82
com.jcraft.jsch.Session#read at line:908
com.jcraft.jsch.Session#run at line:1378
java.lang.Thread#run at line:74
```

Please let me know if i am missing any configuration

Answer (score 0):

1. I fail to see how this code can work as your `i` is not defined anywhere so it will not even compile
2. It seems that some thread(s) cannot be finished because they are still reading something, I believe you have some form of [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) or [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) which define the maximum acceptable time for the file upload operation and your test seems to be exceeding this time.

   So before calling `def sftpSession = session.connect()` I would recommend placing the [Session.setTimeout()](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setTimeout-int-) function call like:

   ```
   session.setTimeout(5000)
   ```

   this way if the operation is not finished in 5 seconds your sampler will fail

If you're not too comfortable with Groovy scripting using [SSH SFTP](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) sampler might be much easier, check out [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter/) article for more details.

Comment: I have updated the code for `i` that was mistakenly written. I tried using `session.setTimeout(5000)` for uploading 110 files but still uploads 106 or 104 sometimes and still works for 100 files.